# How Can I compare (pictureBox1.Image with Properties.Resources.bug1)?

Tags: c#, equals, picturebox

How I Can tell if that image(pictureBox1.Image) is the same as image from Properties.Resources.bug1 ???

I read that i cant do it in that form :

```
if (pictureBox1.Image == Properties.Resources.bug1)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("here");
 }
```

I found this "You need your own Image comparison algorithm if you need to compare it. You'd do it by comparing pixel by pixel."

so what that mean, How I can do it properly??

Answer (score 0):

I'm working under the assumption that, at some point in your code, you are doing something like

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.bug1;
```

If you're getting the image from elsewhere and it differs in some small way, this method **won't work**. I'm sure there are better, more efficient ways of doing this, but here's something:

1. Convert image1 to a byte array.
2. Convert image2 to a byte array.
3. Compare these arrays to see if they're the same.

   ```
   private byte[] GetImageBytes(Image img)
   {
       using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
       {
           ImageConverter imgConverter = new ImageConverter();
           return (byte[])imgConverter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
       }
   }
   ```

   Implementation:

   ```
   bool sameImage = GetImageBytes(pictureBox1.Image).SequenceEqual(GetImageBytes(Properties.Resources.bug1));
   ```